# JNA equivalent of HANDLE*

Tags: java, java-native-interface, jna

I have to use a c function defined in a third-party dll

```
__declspec(dllimport) Init(DWORD id,HANDLE* handle);
```

JNAerate was kind enough to generate the following the method signature....

```
public static native int Init(int id,PointerByReference handle);
```

And using it as

```
public interface Dll extends Library
{
    public Dll _dll = (Dll)Native.LoadLibrary("dll_name");
    public int Init(int id,PointerByReference handle);
}

public void init()
{
     long hwnd = 0;
     LongByReference lbr = new LongByRefrence(hwnd);
     PointerByReference pbr = new PointerByReference();
     pbr.setPointer(lbr.getPointer());
     int ret = _dll.init(0x01,pbr);
}
```

but this crashes the JVM.. can someone please tell me the appropriate way to map a void** in JNA.

Answer (score 0):

`PointerByReference.getValue()` provides you with the value "returned" by the callee.  That is the value you can then use to initialize a HANDLE value.  There is no need to "initialize" the `PointerByReference`.

```
public void init()
{
     PointerByReference pbr = new PointerByReference();
     int ret = _dll.init(0x01,pbr);
     HANDLE handle = new HANDLE(pbr.getValue());
}
```

Comment: I tried that but still the same result. JVM crashes saying EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005)..

Comment: Is `pbr.getValue()` null?  If `_dll.init()` returns an invalid value you certainly shouldn't use it.

Comment: jvm crashes on the `_dll.init()` line itself, ... As of now i managed to use this dll using JNI and working perfectly.. Maybe i would give JNA a try another time

Comment: Is `Init()` expecting something special about its arguments?  Is the `HANDLE*` supposed to be initialized in some way?

Comment: no `HANDLE` is initialized by `Init()`. Here is the jni code i am using `HANDLE hwnd; int ret = Init(id,&hwnd);` where `id` is passed as the parameter to the JNI function and casting `hwnd` to `long` and returning it to java.

Comment: Is your API using the stdcall calling convention?  If so, you need `StdCallLibrary` rather than `Library`.  Other than that, the example code in the answer is correct for the API as you've described it.

Comment: No it does'nt use stdcall calling convention, but still already gave that a try, also tried using `WinNT.HandleByReference` but same result - jvm crashes

Comment: Technically, you should make your `Init` mapping return `int` rather than `void`, although that's unlikely to cause a crash.